# App bundle - cannot find dynamic feature source dir

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

When using dynamic feature, I need to find the source dir of the split apk downloaded after the dynamic module had been installed.
When installing from Android studio,  I'm able to get the path to the split apk by using `context.getApplicationInfo().splitSourceDirs`

When testing the dynamic feature via Google Play, the `splitSourceDirs` only contains the configuration and the resolution apk paths.

How can I get the path to the downloaded apk?

I tried to use the new context method unsuccessfully
`context.createPackageContext(context.packageName, 0)`

Comment: is this for O+? pre-O and O+ are slightly different. https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#aia_update_context

Comment: I'm currently testing on O, but note that the link above is for instant apps.
I have no problem to access assets, the issue is with raw resources

Comment: Have you tried `splitPublicSourceDirs` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo#splitPublicSourceDirs? *"including resources and manifest"*

Comment: Tried `splitPublicSourceDirs` unsuccessfully

Comment: Were you able to figure this out ?

Comment: @duskandawn I didn't follow up on this as I moved on from that project